# Welchen Effekt haben bestimmte Artikel mit eindeutigen Personennamen?

Tags: definite-article, proper-noun, person-names

Ich habe den folgenden Satz gelesen:

> Den Move würd ich morgen gern vom Jan sehen.

Jan ist eine Person, und in diesem Kontext gibt es nur *einen* Jan – es besteht also keine Mehrdeutigkeit. Welchen Zweck hat hier der Artikel? Soll er vermindern oder "freundlich" wirken?

Comment: Ich habe mir erlaubt, die Frage ein wenig zu bearbeiten. Ich hoffe, das mit dem "freundlich" war so gemeint. Ansonsten bitte anmerken.

Comment: @splattne: Super, danke. (Ich verwende aber lieber `--` wenn es kein n-dash gibt.)

Comment: @Tim_N Hab dem Satz einen Gedankenstrich verpasst. So heißt das Ding übrigens auf Deutsch. *Sprache der Dichter und Denker und so...* ;)

Comment: @splattne Viel besser :)

Comment: Was bitte ist ein Move?  Wenn ich raten müsste, würde ich ein englisches Fremdwort für eine Tanzbewegung oder so etwas vermuten.

Comment: @bernd_k: Erraten. In diesem Fall ist es eine Kampfsportbewegung.

Comment: _Der_ Bastian Sick hat auch mal einen Artikel darüber geschrieben: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,623493,00.html

Answer (score 7):

In Deutsch wird normalerweise kein Artikel vor Personennamen verwendet. Wie das in der Umgangssprache durchaus übliche Beispiel zeigt, gibt es allerdings ein paar Ausnahmen.

Ich zitiere den Wikipedia-Artikel *[Eigennamen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenname#Personennamen)* [Nummerierung von mir]:

> 1. Soll der Person eine bestimmte Eigenschaft zugeschrieben werden, ist jedoch der bestimmte Artikel zu gebrauchen ("der junge Goethe").
> 2. Wird der bestimmte Artikel vor Nachnamen verwandt, drückt er entweder eine abwertende Haltung aus ("Der Müller hat wieder mal seine Rechnung nicht bezahlt") oder
> 3. eine berühmte Persönlichkeit heraus ("die Callas sang").
> 4. Bei Nachstellungen eines Eigennamens ist der Artikel verpflichtend ("Sie wird eigentlich von allen geliebt, die Sandra").

Im obigen Beispiel ist es zwar nicht offensichtlich, aber es ist doch eine kleine, subtile **versteckte Abwertung** impliziert, im Sinne (Lehrerin/Trainer sagt zur Gruppe):

> Den Move würd ich morgen gern vom Jan sehen, *von dem ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob er ihn beherrscht.*

Comment: Ich lese es umgekehrt, so als würde Jan den Move sicher eleganter ausführen. Ich kenne aber Jan nicht. :) Prinzipiell sollte es aber "... gerne von Jan sehen" heißen.

Answer (score 4):

Ich dachte eigentlich immer, "von Jan" oder "vom Jan" wäre mehr ein regionaler Unterschied.  Wenn jemand "Vom Jan" sagt, würde ich auf eine süddeutsche Herkunft tippen, bei "von Jan" mehr auf nördlich (der Mainlinie oder wasauchimmer man als Trennungslinie sieht ;-)).

Nee, Beweise für die These habe ich nicht (genauso wenig wie meine Vorantworter ;-)).

Comment: +1 for pointing to possible regional differences

Comment: Für süddeutsch kann ich das nur bestätigen und die Trennlinie heißt Weißwurstäquator :)

Comment: Als Nordlicht kann ich bestätigen, dass es hier um regionale Unterschiede geht.

Answer (score 3):

Das ist eine knifflige Frage, weil es um einen subtilen Unterschied geht. Genauso richtig wäre nämlich auch der Satz:

> Den Move würde ich morgen gerne von Jan sehen.

Im genannten Beispiel wird aber `vom` als Kurzform zu `von dem` eingesetzt. Damit wird auch die Beziehung zur angesprochenen Person verstärkt; man kennt die Person nicht nur, sondern man kennt sie gut. Das verdeutlichen auch folgende Beispiele:

> Jan hat gestern gesagt...
>
> Der Jan hat gestern gesagt...

Dies muss keineswegs mit Freundlichkeit verknüpft sein:

> Wer hat den Krug zerbrochen? - Jan hat das getan.
>
> Wer hat den Krug zerbrochen? - Der Jan hat das getan.

Answer (score 3):

In Österreich ist der Unterschied im wesentlichen: gesprochene Sprache mit Artikel, geschriebene Sprache ohne Artikel, es sei denn, man will bewußt den Eindruck einer gesprochenen Erzählung erzielen.

Comment: So da man sagt immer "Ich hab mit dem thei gegessen", mit Artikel?

Comment: Nein, denn ich bin weiblich :)

Dein Beispielsatz klingt auch sonst komisch für mich, ich würde wohl sagen: "Ich war gestern mit dem Tim essen." oder "Der Tim war gestern bei mir zum Abendessen.", aber "Ich hab mit dem Tim darüber gesprochen." klingt für mich normal.

Comment: Achso :) Danke, das war interessant!

Answer (score 0):

Zunächst stimme ich splattne zu.

**Ergänzung:**

Die Frage sagt Personennamen - Das Beispiel gebraucht Vornamen.

Allgemein im Zusammenhang mit Nachnamen, könnte **vom** auch ein Namenszusatz sein. Ich kenne es als möglicher Auswahlwert für Namenszusätze aus einem Programm um Personendaten zu erfassen.

Adelsprädikate und Namenszusätze ist sicher eine eigene Frage(n) wert.

Comment: Achso. Ich glaubte, dass "Personenname" "name of a person" bedeutete.

Comment: _Personenname_ klingt nach Behördendeutsch.

Comment: @bernd_k: Was wurdest du sagen? "Namen" beinhaltet auch Handelsmärke.

Comment: @tim Meinst du Namen beinhalten auch Markennamen oder Handelsnamen  ?

Comment: @bernd_k: Genau. Ist es nicht so?

Comment: Der Adel ist abgeschafft.

Comment: @user unkown Behauptest du das auch noch, wenn der Adlige dein Kunde ist?

Comment: @tim N Ich denke _name of a person_ ist besser mit _Name einer Person_ zu übersetzen_.

Comment: bernd_k: Das kann nicht passieren, weil es keine Adligen gibt. Die "Frau im Spiegel" und ähnliche Blätter mögen sich den Feudalismus zurückwünschen - ich nicht. Und derzeit gibt es keinen Adel, das ist nun mal Fakt.