# Wie werden Namen von Adligen in Briefadressen korrekt angegeben?

Tags: politeness

Wie sieht die korrekte Namensangabe von Adligen in Adressfeldern und Briefanreden aus, so wie sie Geschäftsleute, Behörden und Krankenhäuser verwenden?

**Edit:**

Ich meine eher die Namenszusätze wie in

> Herr Karl Theodor **zu** Gutenberg
>
> So und So Straße yy
>
> XXXX X-Stadt

Die Frage ist meine Reaktion auf einige Kommentare zu meiner [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/983/welchen-effekt-haben-bestimmte-artikel-mit-eindeutigen-personennamen/992#992), wo behauptet wird das es in Deutschland keinen Adel gibt. Es geht darum ob diese zu berücksichtigen sind oder fortgelassen werden dürfen.

Es geht nicht um die Frage Adel oder nicht Adel.

Hier geht es um die Frage Namensbestandteile adliger Herkunft.

Praktisch bedeutsam ist das, wenn es um die Gestaltung von Serienbriefen geht. Da müssen Textmarken und Datenbankfelder dann zusammenpassen. Diese Aufgabe ist definitiv nicht ganz einfach. Außer im Adressfeld und in der Anrede (Sehr geehrte(r) ...) kann der Name auch noch im Textinneren erwähnt werden. Das ist zugegebenermaßen ein umfassenderes Problem, wobei die Namensbestandteile adliger Herkunft nur ein Teilaspekt sind.

Comment: Hast du eine konkrete Situation? Die Frage wird sonst wahrscheinlich  zu "open-ended"

Comment: Wer ist adlig ?

Comment: @Tim_N Fürstinnen, Grafen, Barone, Prinzessinen, ... "von und zu"-Leute

Comment: In Österreich wurden übrigens Adelstitel mit dem Adelsaufhebungsgesetz 1919 verboten – anerkannt sind hier nur die im Ausland zulässigen Titel. In der Schweiz waren Adelstitel seit eidgenössischer Zeit nicht möglich.

Comment: Der Adel ist abgeschafft. Es gibt keine Fürten, Barone, Herzoge, Könige und Kaiser mehr. Get over it. Was es gibt, das sind Namensbestandteile, und dann muß man eben den Namen wissen, und diesen auf den Brief schreiben, wie bei Simone Greiner Petter-Memm. M.a.W.: Der Herr heißt 'zu Guttenberg', aber es ist kein Adelstitel.

Comment: "Herr Karl Theodor zu Gutenberg" darf man auf jeden Fall anschreiben mit "Herr Hieronymus Carl Friedrich von Münchhausen" - Der Brief dürfte ankommen ;-)

Comment: Ich fürchte ich hätte bei der Wahl des Beispielnamens mehr Sorgfalt walten lassen müssen, um ein geringere Anzahl humorvoller Kommentare zu provozieren.

Answer (score 3):

Für deutsche Adelstitel gilt folgende Reihenfolge (entnommen aus dem [Wikipedia-Artikel über Adelstitel):](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelstitel#Verwendung)

1. Persönliche Anrede (Herr oder Frau).
2. staatliche oder kirchliche Ehrentitel
3. Amtsbezeichnung  oder Dienstgrad  oder akademische Titel
4. Akademische Grade, die vor dem Namen zu führen sind, in absteigender Folge
5. Vorname
6. Nachname, **einschließlich des ehemaligen Adelsprädikats, da Teil des Namens**
7. Akademische Grade, die hinter dem Namen zu führen sind in aufsteigender Folge

Daraus konstruiere ich das fiktive Beispiel:

> An Herrn Prälat Prof. Mag.phil. Dr.iur. Gustav Baron von Münchhausen

---

Die Anrede richtet sich übrigens nach dem [Adelsprädikat](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelspr%C3%A4dikat#Anrede).

Comment: Was davon ist jetzt Baron und was ist von?

Comment: Der Nachname ist laut deutschem Recht alles zusammen: "Baron von Münchhausen"

Comment: D.h. eine Zerlegung in Namensvorsatz + Nachname + Namens zusatz ist eine interne EDV Technische Angelegenheit, um gezielt den Münchhausen finden zu können?

Comment: Da bin ich leider überfragt. Kann mir aber vorstellen, dass manche Datenbanken das so handhaben.

Comment: @splattne: Die "absteigende Folge" ist verwirrend, da du ein gegenteiliges Beispiel bringst. Tatsächlich ist sowohl Mag. Dr. als auch Dr. Mag. möglich und bedeutet etwas Verschiedenes.

Comment: @thei ja, in Wikipedia ist auch so ein Beispiel; in Österreich ists aufsteigend; ehrlich gesagt geht mir dieser Titelquatsch auf die Nerven und v.a. die Leute, die auf ihre eigenen Titel pochen. :)

Comment: @splattne Für dich immer noch Dr. thei, bitteschön.

Comment: @splattne: Wikipedia hat in diesem Punkt übrigens nicht recht. In Österreich kann man Mag.Dr. Dipl.Ing sein. Es bedeutet, dass das Doktorat auf Basis eines Magistertitels erworben wurde und der Diplomingenieur zusätzlich in einem anderen Fach erworben wurde.

Comment: Und was ist mit den militärischen Rängen - wo fügt sich da der Hauptfeldwebel/Gebirgsjägermajor/Generalhusar/Unterfregattenkapitän ein?

Comment: Ein Rang ist kein Titel, WIMNI.  Also: ich würd ihn komplett weglassen.  Wenn ich mit einem Militär egal welchen Ranges zu tun hätte, dann in rein ziviler Funktion, und dann ist er/sie für mich nur Zivilist, und Zivilisten haben keinen milit. Rang. :D

Comment: @jae: Das ist bei militärischen Titeln wie bei akademischen Titeln: Wenn du willst, dass dich dein Taxifahrer rasch zum Flughafen bringt, dann sprichst du ihn besser mit Doktor an, und wenn du an der amerikanischen Botschaft vorbeigehen willst, dann bist du besser auch gaanz höflich (und hast als Mann keine langen Haare und sonstige Respektlosigkeiten). :)

Comment: @thei: not to try to be a Klugscheisser, aber war der Kontext nicht "Briefadressen"? ;-)  Und: wie ich schrieb: es gibt keine militärischen Titel (falls du was anderes weisst, bitte Link, aber in DE sind militärische Dienstgrade def. keine Titel).  Und dann: an der amerikanischen Botschaft würde ich gar nix sagen, wenn ich dran *vorbei* gehe ;-) Und drinnen?  Na, den Marine würde ich wohl einfach mit "Entschuldigen Sie, ich hätte da ne Frage" ansprechen (oder "Excuse me, ...").  Weil ich da eh nicht sicher wüsste, ob das jetzt ein Private, ein Sergeant oder ein Butterbar ist ;-)