# How to address people with a preposition in their family name properly?

Tags: salutation, letter, person-names

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Wie werden Namen von Adligen in Briefadressen korrekt angegeben?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/wie-werden-namen-von-adligen-in-briefadressen-korrekt-angegeben)*

As in other languages, sometimes you can encounter German names with prepositions in the family name. Here some examples:

- Wernher von Braun
- Karl August von Hardenberg
- Heinrich von Kleist

How can I address these people properly? Furthermore, if there are variants, which one is kind or stuck-up.

When I greet someone in an email or in person, which of the following should I use?

> Guten Tag, Herr Braun
>   Guten Tag, Herr von Braun

When I talk with another person about the person with the preposition in his/her name, should which of the following should I use?

> Gerne treffe ich mich mit Herrn Braun.
>   Gerne treffe ich mich mit Herrn von Braun.

Answer (score 6):

Der Adel ist in Deutschland abgeschafft. Die Präpositionen werden aber als Namensbestandteil fortgeführt.

Informell mögen sich die Personen anders nennen lassen, aber informell ist ja ohnehin alles möglich. Formal ist also das Von zu benutzen:

```
Guten Tag Herr von Blau.
Gerne treffe ich mich mit Frau von Bülow.
```