# Was ist der Zweck von "dem" als Artikel "Das ist übrigens dem Peter passiert"

Tags: word-usage

Aus *Teach Yourself. Improve your German* Von Paul Coggle und Heiner Schenke

> Das ist übrigens **dem** Peter passiert, und jetzt hat er das neue Auto zu
>   Hause stehen, das ihm seine Eltern schon vorher gekauft hatten, und
>   kann nicht damit fahren.

Warum wird *dem* verwendet?

Comment: Similar: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/983/welchen-effekt-haben-bestimmte-artikel-mit-eindeutigen-personennamen/

Comment: @DavidVogt, na ja, also, es ist (2), Eine Abwertung

Comment: @user5389726598465: Es ist hier keine Abwertung, es drückt nur aus, dass Peter ein gemeinsamer Bekannter ist. Es ist nicht *irgendein Peter*, sondern ***der** Peter*.

Comment: @CarstenS how embarassing. I thought I had asked this before and looked through my questions and then didn't see it...

Comment: @user5389726598465 , here to help :)

Comment: gemeinsamer Bakannter finde ich gut.  ... "dem Peter"klingt irgendwie auch familiär.